# Is it possible to display the assertion results in the View Results Tree listener itself in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, assert

Is there anyway we can display the assertion results in the View Results Tree listener itself? Also, the Assertion Results listener displays only failed assertions, is there a simple way to display both the failed as well as the passed assertions preferably in a verbose manner?

Answer (score 1):

View Results Tree Listener displays failed assertions:

[image: Failed Assertion]

If you're doing some functional testing with low number of virtual users (threads) and  need to see verbose assertion results you need to choose a more advanced assertion, i.e. [Beanshell Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Assertion) or [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) which have full control of response data, headers, messages, sample labels, log file, etc. so you will be able to precisely do what you need using JMeter API in [Beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/) or [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language

If you're running a load test which assumes immense load - I would strongly recommend to:

- Forget about running JMeter in GUI mode
- Disable all the listeners, **especially** View Results Tree
- Leave only those assertions which are absolutely required.

Otherwise overhead caused by listeners memory consumption and IO to write all the things down on JMeter side can ruin your load test and results won't be relevant. See [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) guide for more detailed explanation of the above points and few more JMeter tuning tweaks.